# Limit number of result or rows returned in BO using WebI

Tags: business-objects, infoview

How do I to limit the number of results/rows returned from a query in WebI other than using custom SQL? Possibly something like 'Top 100' records.

I can't change the 'Limit resultant size' in the parameters as I do not want it to affect any other reports.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Web Intelligence, you can set the number of rows that the query provider should retrieve. This setting is called the *Max rows retrieved*. From the Webi user guide:

> The Max rows retrieved query property determines the maximum number of
>   rows of data that are displayed when a query is run.
>
> If you only need a certain amount of data, you can set this value to
>   limit the number of rows of data in your document.
>
> Max rows retrieved is applied at the database level if the database
>   supports it. If not, rows are discarded after retrieval from the
>   database.

Note: this setting is linked to the query, not the document as a whole. In other words, if your document has multiple queries, you have to set the Max rows retrieved for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you define your report on a Universe, you can also limit the size of the result set in Universe Parameters -> Controls.

Comment: The OP's question mentioned that he did not want to affect any other documents. Changing the setting on a universe level would impact all documents based on that universe.