# Set max lines displayed in WebI BO report

Tags: business-objects

How would I set a maximum lines to display in a BO 4 report? On each page, I'd like to show 20 account numbers in column 1 with item counts in the next columns. There are some good discussions on limiting the rows retrieved in a query (e.g., [Limit number of result or rows returned in BO using WebI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968696/limit-number-of-result-or-rows-returned-in-bo-using-webi)). Some suggestions include using sections with RowIndex()/20 to limit the lines to 20, so I tried adding a variable =Floor(RowIndex()/20).  However, the lines in my report contain aggregated variables, and the row index counts all records retrieved. Thoughts?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share what you have tried? Please edit your Q and post code.

Comment: I don't have access to view SQL, but I added the variable syntax above.

Answer (score 1):

One option:

Add a column on the far left of the block.  Use the following formula:

```
=Floor(RunningCount([Account Number])/10)
```

(assuming, of course, that your dimension is named `[Account Number]`)

Create a break on this column.  (Report Element -> Table Layout -> Break -> Add Break).  Go back to the same menu and click Manage Breaks.  Click the "Start on a new page" checkbox.

This will create a block with a maximum of 20 rows per page.  Unfortunately, there's no direct way to hide a column in WebI, so you'd be stuck with this ugly column.  What you can do, however, is remove all borders, change the font to white-on-white, and reduce its width as much as possible.